# Navigation Controller not showing Root View (just white space)

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, segue

long time lurker first time poster here. My question is about Navigation Controllers in Xcode 6.1.1.

Basically I've created a feed app that grabs posts from my Wordpress Site and shows them in a table list. When an item from the list is selected, a web view shows the url from the selected item. I want to manage moving between these two views (table and webview) with a navigation controller, so I embedded one into the table list view on my storyboard establishing the table view as the Root. When I run the app, I get a blank screen with an empty navigation bar at the top of the screen (nav controller is set to initial view). I expect to see the list view inside the controller but I get nada. In the past I've been able to do this without writing any code and it's worked no problem.

Not sure why this is happening, but I'm sure it's something really simple that I'm overlooking. Any help would be awesome. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Did you change the class of the view controller with the table to your custom class? Did you set the data source and delegate (only if you're using a UIViewController; that's done for you if you're using a UITableViewController)?

Comment: It's set to ViewController class, and if I understand your second question correctly, yes it has source and delegate assigned. I also should have mentioned that without the navigation controller embedded, the list populates just fine and I'm able to select feed items from the table and view them via the web view. It's when I embed the controller that things go blank.

Comment: There's no reason embedding our view controller in a navigation controller should make your table view not work that I can think of. So, is your structure NavContollerer --> (root)TableViewController  --> WebViewController? And it's the TableViewController that's blank right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly right. At run time I get the empty view

Comment: Does viewDidLoad run in the tableViewController? Do any of the data source methods?

Comment: Yeah, the viewDidLoad is inside the table view (the file is ViewController.m), that's the only place in the file where I'm assigning data source and delegate

Comment: Do numberOfRowsInSection or cellForRowAtIndexPath run?

Comment: Yeah those two are included as well and they appear to function just fine since the table is populating and each row is selectable.

Comment: Wtf? You say in your title that you only see white, now you say you see the table view?

Comment: Haha I know it's really odd. Before I added the nav item, it would run with an empty nav bar at the top and a blank view. Added the nav item and gave it a title. Now it works just fine. Thanks for all your replies though, rdelmar.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue. I knew it was going to be something really small. All I had to do was add a Navigation Item to the Table View Controller. Once I gave the nav item a title, I embedded the Navigation Controller and everything works as expected now.

I got the idea by throwing a navigation controller object onto my story board and cross referencing the canned relationship against my own and that's the only thing that was missing. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Something must have been odd about your setup because you shouldn't have to add a navigation item when you embed a controller in a navigation controller -- it should be there automatically. BTW, you don't embed the navigation controller, you embed some other controller in the navigation controller. I have no idea what you mean by "cross referencing the canned relationship against my own". The way you should do this, if you are starting with a stand-alone controller, is go to the edit menu, and choose "embed in navigation controller". That's all you should have to do.

Comment: That's what I meant sorry. Embedding the table view into the navigation controller is what I did. the cross reference bit means I grabbed a nav controller from the object library, threw it onto my storyboard, and then compared it to the navigation controller i added using "embed in." The only thing missing was a nav item in my root view. If you look at nav controller object it has a view controller attached called "root view controller" and you can see that there's a nav item with the title "root view controller" included too. I think I probably had one and deleted it at some point by accident